# Can't get my load more divs to work

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to sort this problem for the last 2 hours. I have no experience in JavaScript, and I hope to get some help here. Does anyone know what is wrong with the file(s)? I think it have something to do with the javaScript file. Thanks for the help in advance!

PS!: It seems to be working just fine in JSFiddle and CodePen but not when I use it IN my pc.

```js
var $group = $('.item');

$(".load-more").click(function() {

  var $hidden = $group.filter(':hidden:first');
  $hidden.addClass('active');
  $hidden.next().addClass('active');
  $hidden.next().next().addClass('active');

  // remove Load More Div - if no more divs
  if (!$hidden.next('.item').length) {
    $(this).remove();
  }

});
```

```css
.item {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  transition: 0.3s all;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px green;
  display: none;
}

.item.active {
  display: block;
}

.load-more {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>

  <div class="item active">
    First div
  </div>

  <div class="item active">
    hidden, opened after click
  </div>

  <div class="item active">
    hidden, opened after click
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    hidden, opened after click
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    hidden, opened after click
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    hidden, opened after click
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    hidden, opened after click
  </div>

  <div class="load-more">
    <p>Load More</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: you should see errors in your browser console

Comment: All works fine here, so: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Does your code appear before or after the import of jQuery? (Has to be after to work.) Have you checked for error messages in the developer console?

Comment: It would be nice if JSFiddle had a "save as html page" button.

Comment: There are no errors in the browser console

Comment: Thanks @Pointy . It was as you said

Comment: put your js code inside `$( document ).ready(function(){ \\insert code here  })` then the click event will bind correctly.

Comment: Why are there $ in front of normal variables?  I assume it doesn't make a difference, but it hurts my brain.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Put you JS code inside document ready event call back.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){ 

    //insert you js code here
})
```

This will help to properly bind click events

### Solution 2

In the stack-overflow code snippet, your example is saving as below. Just copy following to index.html and try to open in your browser it will work
**Because your JS code is inside the `body` tag and click event bind will happen after the document is loaded. try to put your js code inside `head` tag it will not work, since the document is not already loaded**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .item {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  transition: 0.3s all;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px green;
  display: none;
}

.item.active {
  display: block;
}

.load-more {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>

  <div class="item active">
    First div
  </div>

  <div class="item active">
    hidden, opened after click
  </div>

  <div class="item active">
    hidden, opened after click
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    hidden, opened after click
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    hidden, opened after click
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    hidden, opened after click
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    hidden, opened after click
  </div>

  <div class="load-more">
    <p>Load More</p>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $group = $('.item');

$(".load-more").click(function() {

  var $hidden = $group.filter(':hidden:first');
  $hidden.addClass('active');
  $hidden.next().addClass('active');
  $hidden.next().next().addClass('active');

  // remove Load More Div - if no more divs
  if (!$hidden.next('.item').length) {
    $(this).remove();
  }

});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```